# Javascript move target around screen?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

So I'm working on a basic shooter, part of which involves moving a target around the screen. I'm using babylon.js as the engine and my goal is to have the target appear for 0.75 seconds on the screen, then disappear for 0.5 seconds, then reappear at a different random location. The current code I have for that is this:

```
function moveTarget(canvas, scene){
  setTimeout( function (){
    scene.meshes[10].visibility = 0; //how I access the target object
    randX = genRandNum(minX, maxX); //This is a separate function that works
    randY = genRandNum(minY, maxY);
    scene.meshes[10].position = new BABYLON.Vector3(randX, randY, 
                 scene.meshes[10].position.z);
    scene.meshes[10].visibility = 1;
    x ++;
    if (x < amount){
      moveTarget(canvas, scene);
    }
  }, tarDuration * 1000)

  }
```

which succeeds in everything except the 0.5 second delay between appearances of the target, ie currently it flashes from location to location with no space in between. I'm thinking that I need a second setTimeout but I'm not entirely sure how to include that or where it would go. Any pushes in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to set a timeout for the full cycle time (0.75 s + 0.5 s) and then another timeout inside that for the 0.5 s delay.

```
function moveTarget(canvas, scene){
    setTimeout( function (){
        setTimeout( function(){
            // Your other code
            x ++;
            if (x < amount){
                moveTarget(canvas, scene);
            }
        }, yourDelayHere)
    }, tarDuration * 1000)
}
```

Where yourDelayHere gives the desired 0.5 s delay. I created a `Babylon.js` playround which shows a simplified example [here](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#AEQY60).